# Output of C++ function system(command) does not show color in Linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, stdout

When I directly run a command in my Linux terminal, say "ls", the output is with color. However, when I run a C++ program which calls system("ls"), the output does not have color.

Is there way to get the latter way to also display colored output?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you do a `system("ls");`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer for why there's no color lies [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
>   command, and returns after the command has been completed.

`sh -c` ignores aliases. Perhaps somewhere you have an alias where `ls` means `ls --color=auto`.

So for example, if I do `sh -c 'ls'`, I will get no color.

Proof:

```
wow ♪[01:04 AM][vnbraun@chernobyl ~]$ which ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        /bin/ls
wow ♪[01:08 AM][vnbraun@chernobyl ~]$ sh -c 'which ls'
/bin/ls
```

Therefore, you can try doing `system("ls --color=auto");`.

Answer (score 4):

You could run

```
 system("/bin/ls --color=auto");
```

But I don't think you really should run `ls` from your C++ program. Perhaps you want to use -some combination of- [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) etc etc....

I don't think that forking a shell which then runs `/bin/ls` is useful from a C++ program. There are simpler ways to achieve your goal (which I cannot guess).

You probably should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking `ls --color=auto` or `ls --color=always` to display `ls` with colors.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a bash configuration file somewhere in your system aliasing "ls" to "ls --color".

Using "ls --color" in your program should work.